# Relation between app version in itunes connect and version we specify in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any relation between app version name we give in itunes connect and version we specify in xcode? Does both have to be same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be same, Else when you upload a binary it'll say that version numbers does not match and show errors.

According to [iTunesConnect Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1):

> Important: Make sure this App Store version number matches the version
>   number set in the bundle. If these don’t match, upload errors for
>   later updates might occur.

Comment: My app is in 'waiting for Review' state. Is there a way to change the version name.

Comment: Waiting for review, yes. You can reject it and change version number on iTunes Connect and Upload a new binary with new version number.